# Django no context data

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I try to show data on template. But context data is empty on html page. 
**views.py**

```py
from .models import DataS

def index(request):
    list_z = DataS.objects.all().count()
    context = {'list_z:': list_z}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>Page</head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>{{ list_z }}</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Either try to just pass in context instead of context=context, or perhaps you've forgotten to include your index function in your urls.py?

Comment: @jasonmzx if I do HttpResponse(list_z) it return the counted value. HttpResponse(context) returns " 'list_z' ".  INdex is included in urls `from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]`

Comment: Can you add your urls.py  here? Also what variables from DataS you want to list in your html file?

Comment: Please add another test variable in your context (example like: a = 5, context = { 'list_z':list_z, 'a':a } and show a in your template.

Comment: @NguyễnVũThiên 'a' shows up.

Comment: Ok so problem is your `list_z`, please check your model `DataS.objects.all()`. 
Use command `print(DataS.objects.all())`. Can it return any object in terminal?

Comment: @NguyễnVũThiên yes it return `nameAnameBnameC`. Also it return `count()` = `3`

Comment: Ok next step, we need to check your html template, your script. Maybe css or js hide it. Please check out.

Comment: @NguyễnVũThiên no css or js used in template

Comment: Maybe you have more than one `index.html` and it's picking up the wrong one.

Comment: Please check a last time, add `<script> var a = '{{ list_z }}'; console.log('count', a);</script>` in your `</body>` html file. Can it show value in console of browser?

Comment: @NguyễnVũThiên no. Only `count`.

Comment: OMG now I realize in your `context = {'list_z:': list_z}`. Just remove `:` in `list_z:`. Change it to `context = {'list_z': list_z}`.

Comment: @NguyễnVũThiên omg, thank you. That typo was so bas :D